# Tenses in clauses with conditionals

Tags: tenses, conditionals

If you could go back in time, what would you do so that you ___ your life lived without regrets?

1. will have
2. would have
3. have
4. would have had

My questions:

1. Is this a badly written sentence? How do I make it right?
2. Which answer will natives go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To have one's life lived" is used very rarely, and essentially in the expression "have one's life lived **for** oneself" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+your+life+lived%2Chave+your+life+lived%2Chad+his+life+lived%2Chave+his+life+lived%2Chave+their+life+lived&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20his%20life%20lived%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20his%20life%20lived%3B%2Cc0) (result for the research "had your life lived,have your life lived,had his life lived,**have his life lived**,have their life lived", [**have his life lived**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have%20his%20life%20lived%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)). I believe that the sentence is not idiomatic, the tense of the verb being a separate matter.

- If you could go back in time, what would you do so that you ___ your life without regrets?

In such a context nothing is more sure to be irreproachable as a simple infinitival construction.

- If you could go back in time, what would you do so as to live your life without regrets?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please enlighten me as to why this question is off-topic as warned by the forum? It's very confusing.

Comment: @Kevin There are sometimes obvious reasons which make a question off-topic, as for instance when someone asks for the explanation of a long sentence or of a particular point of syntax in some _programming language_. In any case of closing, unless a moderator decides it, the closing of the question has to be voted by at least three of the members of the ELU who have the privilege of voting to close questions (still recently, it was five; minimum reputation 3 000; check out "Help center", bottom of the page, then "privileges"). In certain cases there is no clear cut  (1/4)

Comment: @Kevin choice and some people do not vote the closing  while others do; however, most often, serious participants to the site leave a comment for the reason of their vote, which is  always valuable information, in particular in doubtful cases, as that of your question. A tangible aspect of this closing procedure which shows that the closing of a question is not necessarily an absolute sanction is the possibility to reopen a closed question as soon as it has been closed (button "Reopen"), and people with the right to vote to close can do that; therefore, when (2/4)

Comment: @Kevin  three of them have voted to reopen they have proved the three preceding voters "wrong", or rather that they do not constitute a majority. In the case of your question, I suspect the problem would be that you are asking for the parsing of the sentence and not for a specific point in it, but, of course, this is understandable, since if you had been able to identify a precise point about which you were in doubt you would have mentioned it. Possibly, if you had asked whether "you do so that you ___ your life lived" was correct, the question would not have been closed as (3/4)

Comment: @Kevin off-topic, but then in this latter case it could have been closed because of lack of research (mentioned in the Help center). Nevertheless, a considerable number of questions do not show any research; in a certain number of those cases the poster just mentions that nothing could be found, and if that seems plausible to the people evaluating the seriousness of the question, there is no problem; this is to say that there is no absolute necessity of showing some research: the fact that there might not be any research too easy to do is also taken into account. (4/4)